# EF 5.0 Code First - manytomany relationship - fluent api - override the generated mm table with my own

Tags: entity-framework, api, fluent, cfml

I have two entities. Each has a navigation prop to the other, so EF automatically creates a m2m mapping table. My classes are Activity and Trip, so EF creates ActivityTrip to map the relationships. This is wonderful - but:

I need to have extra data in those relationship records, so want to provide my own m2m table and use fluent api to map the relationship to this table instead of auto generated one.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
}

public class Trip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityTrip //Want to use my own manytomany join table with extra fields
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    //Extra data
    public string ActivityTripType { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my configurations:

```
public class ActivityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Activity>
{
    public ActivityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        HasMany(t => t.Trips)
        .WithMany(a => a.Activities)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("ActivityTrip");
            m.MapLeftKey("ActivityId");
            m.MapRightKey("TripId");
        });
    }
}

public class TripConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Trip>
{
    public TripConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
    }
}

public class ActivityTripConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ActivityTrip>
{
    public ActivityTripConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.ActivityId, p.TripId });
    }
}
```

EF still generates it's own ActivityTrip table with the FKs for the m2m relationship. 
EF then generates another ActivityTrip1 table for my coded first ActivityTrip entity with my two primary keys and extra field.

It is not seeing that I want to control the generation of the m2m table. and map the foreign keys to my table. I'm obviously doing this wrong - please advise...

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score -1):

Additional data in the junction table isn't supported by EF, so you will need to treat the data as another entity.

In other words, two one-to-many relationships with an additional entity that represents a record in your junction table.

You have the additional entity type - `ActivityTrip` - but you need to model two one-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply. I will do this and see how it works. However - Question - I understand additional data in the auto generated junction table is not supported. But can't I specify and map my own table that I want to use for the relationship - as long as I configure it correctly? I thought that was what the fluent API was all about when configuring and mapping relationships? Isn't this what you would encounter when mapping to an existing database?

Comment: You can use your own junction table, but in terms of EF it's not modeled as a many-to-many using the Map fluent API method, but just as two one-to-many relationships using the HasRequired/Optional and HasMany fluent API methods. This also makes sense in the object model, as otherwise where would this additional data be stored?